# Responsive GIF background for mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, gif

I have recently created a website that has a gif as a background image. The gif covers the entire screen on a computer, but when I use a mobile device and go onto my website, the gif is only present on the top fraction of the screen, leaving the rest of the space white. I've tried some solutions like putting in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and `background-size: cover;` but that only made my text adjust, and not my gif background. Sorry if this question is stupid, but I appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 2):

use `background-size: cover` for the element to which you applied the GIF as a background image.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that I already had that. thanks though

Comment: Could you explain, then, what's *wrong* with this approach, @WashingMachine? It seems like it'd solve your issue nicely, or the `background-size: contain` option.

Comment: when I added in 'background-size: contain;' nothing really changed, the gif still remains on the top portion of the screen and leaving the bottom portion white. thanks for the suggestion though